# Extracting multiple lines according to a string that is pipe delimited

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script  that would extract every 3 lines according to country field and separate it into 2 text files.
the data look like this:

```
INVHDR|JPN|
INVDET|4254|
INVTOT|3325|
INVHDR|AUS|
INVDET|9685|
INVTOT|1431|
INVHDR|JPN|
INVDET|3368|
INVTOT|1126|
INVHDR|NZL|
INVDET|1458|
INVTOT|5698|
```

all field 2 that is equal to JPN will be joined together
the Output should be for text file 1

```
INVHDR|JPN|
INVDET|4254|
INVTOT|3325|
INVHDR|JPN|
INVDET|3368|
INVTOT|1126|
```

as well as for none JPN will be put to together another text files
and for the other Output should be for text file 2

```
INVHDR|AUS|
INVDET|9685|
INVTOT|1431|
INVHDR|NZL|
INVDET|1458|
INVTOT|5698|
```

I just new in perl and need some selp to enligthen me on this.
thanks for helping me out
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $output1, '>output1.txt'
    or die "Can't open output1.txt for writing: $!\n";

open my $output2, '>output2.txt'
    or die "Can't open output2.txt for writing: $!\n";

my @data = <>;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @data; $i += 3) {
    my $result = join q{}, @data[$i..$i+2];
    my $output = $data[$i] =~ /JPN\|$/ ? $output1 : $output2;
    print $output $result;
}

close $output1;
close $output2;
```

Comment: `$/ = undef; my @data = split "\n", <>;`? `my @data = <>;`. But I'd prefer not to read all of it at once. Just read as many lines as you need for each iteration.

Comment: `perl this_script.pl your_data.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried sed with this:

```
sed -n -e '/JPN/,+2w file1' -e '/JPN/,+2!w file2' yourfile
```